# Storing injected Spring Beans in a HashMap

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

This is a question about the use of Spring for business objects and how they are stored after being injected into classes that need them.

In a typical Spring setup, you might have a business object as follows:

```
package app.service.impl;

public class MaintainStudent implements app.service.intf.MaintainStudent
{
    protected app.dao.intf.CourseDAO courseDAO;
    protected app.dao.intf.StudentDAO studentDAO;
    protected app.dao.intf.CourseAssignDAO courseAssignDAO;

    //injection methods here
    public void setCourseDAO(app.dao.intf.CourseDAO courseDAO)
    {
        this.courseDAO = courseDAO;
    }

    public void setStudentDAO(app.dao.intf.StudentDAO studentDAO)
    {
        this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
    }

    public void setCourseAssignDAO(app.dao.intf.CourseAssignDAO courseAssignDAO)
    {
        this.courseAssignDAO = courseAssignDAO;
    }
    //end injection methods

    //example business method
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
    public void assignCourse(StudentKey studenKey, CourseKey courseKey)
    {
        courseAssignDAO.assignCourse(studentKey, courseKey);
    }

    //rest of the class here
}
```

The bean XML entries for the above might look like this:

```
<bean id="baseDAO" class="app.dao.base.BaseDAO" abstract="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="courseDAO" class="app.dao.impl.CourseDAO"
    parent="baseDAO">
</bean>

<bean id="studentDAO" class="app.dao.impl.StudentDAO"
    parent="baseDAO">
</bean>    

<bean id="courseAssignDAO" class="app.dao.impl.CourseAssignDAO"
    parent="baseDAO">
</bean>

<bean id="maintainStudent" class="app.service.impl.MaintainStudent">
    <property name="courseDAO" ref="courseDAO" />
    <property name="studentDAO" ref="courseAssignDAO" />
    <property name="courseAssignDAO" ref="studentDAO" />
</bean>
```

My question is, is it ok to store the injected beans in a `HashMap` instead of in individual interface variables?  I ask this question because I am working on a porting project for an applicaion I support and I am trying to replace the application's EJB / JDBC transaction architecture with Spring.  I am using Struts2 and Spring as the new architecture for the application.  I am using Spring in this project primarily for its Database Transaction capabilities.  The existing application uses factory classes to instantiate everything, and I have come up with a way of converting the architecture to Dependency Injection using the factory classes by storing the beans in a `HashMap`.

Below is an example of the same business object using my `HashMap` method of storing the beans:

```
package app.service.impl;

public class MaintainStudent extends app.base.BaseBusinessObj
    implements app.service.intf.MaintainStudent
{ 
    //injection methods here
    public void setCourseDAO(app.dao.intf.CourseDAO courseDAO)
    {
        this.springBeans.add(courseDAO.getClass().getName(), courseDAO);
    }

    public void setStudentDAO(app.dao.intf.StudentDAO studentDAO)
    {
        this.springBeans.add(studentDAO.getClass().getName(), studentDAO);
    }

    public void setCourseAssignDAO(app.dao.intf.CourseAssignDAO courseAssignDAO)
    {
        this.springBeans.add(courseAssignDAO.getClass().getName(), courseAssignDAO);
    }
    //end injection methods

    //example business method
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
    public void assignCourse(StudentKey studenKey, CourseKey courseKey)
    {
        app.dao.intf.CourseAssignDAO courseAssignDAO =
            app.dao.fact.CourseAssignDAOFactory.requestBean(this);

        courseAssignDAO.assignCourse(studentKey, courseKey);
    }

    //rest of the class here
}
```

BaseBusinessObj class:

```
package app.base;    

public class BaseBusinessObj implements org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
{
    private Map<String, Object> springBeans = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public void addBean(String className, Object bean)
    {
        this.springBeans.put(className, bean);
    }

    public Object getBean(String className)
    {
        return this.springBeans.get(className);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception
    {
        this.springBeans.clear();
    }
}
```

Modified bean XML entries:

```
<bean id="baseBusinessObj" class="app.base.BaseBusinessObj" abstract="true">
</bean>

<bean id="baseDAO" class="app.dao.base.BaseDAO" abstract="true"
    parent="baseBusinessObj">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="courseDAO" class="app.dao.fact.CourseDAOFactory"
    parent="baseDAO">
</bean>

<bean id="studentDAO" class="app.dao.fact.StudentDAOFactory"
    parent="baseDAO">
</bean>

<bean id="courseAssignDAO" class="app.dao.fact.CourseAssignDAOFactory"
    parent="baseDAO">
</bean>

<bean id="maintainStudent" class="app.service.fact.MaintainStudentFactory"
    parent="baseBusinessObj">
    <property name="courseDAO" ref="courseDAO" />
    <property name="studentDAO" ref="courseAssignDAO" />
    <property name="courseAssignDAO" ref="studentDAO" />
</bean>
```

Sample converted factory class that now serves up an injected bean instead of creating a new instance:

```
package app.dao.fact;

public class CourseAssignDAOFactory extends app.dao.impl.CourseAssignDAO
{
    protected CourseAssignDAOFactory()
    {
        super();
    }

    //method formerly called "newInstance()"
    public static app.dao.intf.CourseAssignDAO requestBean(app.base.BaseBusinessObj requester)
    {
        app.dao.intf.CourseAssignDAO result;
        Object requestedBean = requester.getBean(CourseAssignDAOFactory.class.getName());
        result = (app.dao.intf.CourseAssignDAO)requestedBean;

        return result;
    }
}
```

What my architecture above does is provide the capability of writing code in a traditional non-DI style that allows the developer to explicitly "request" needed objects.  This requesting is a similar activity to creating (instantiating) objects yourself.  In my architecture, 'Requesting a Bean' has replaced 'Creating a New Instance' so that the Factory Class statements can be left in the code while making the code work with Dependency Injection architecture.  I'm going to create a code generator that will automatically generate the required injector methods into every class that needs them.

I have tested the above architecture and it works.  Transactions commit and rollback when expected.

I'm just wondering if this architecture I have created will still allow Spring to behave as designed.

With this architecture, will all of my beans still be able to be destroyed by Spring after a transaction is complete?  Or will there be hanging objects in memory because of the `HashMap` storage idea?

Let me know what you think.  Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: What's the point in storing beans in map? If you don't like injected variables then you can get required bean from spring context.

Comment: @AleksandrM Will calling the getBean method from ApplicationContext to get all of your beans break the transaction?  Or will transactions still propagate, commit, and rollback as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the factories with `Provider<Type>` and have those injected instead:

```
public class CourseAssignDaoUser {

    @Autowired
    private Provider<CourseAssignDao> factory;

    void useDao() {
        CourseAssignDao dao = factory.get();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or even inject the values directly:

```
public class CourseAssignDaoUser {

    @Autowired
    private CourseAssignDao dao;

    void useDao() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If this is not possible for some reason you can use the Spring context instead
of using the map:

```
public class CourseAssignDAOFactory {

    public static CourseAssignDAO requestBean(ApplicationContext context) {
        return context.getBean(CourseAssignDao.class);
    }
}
```

But using `@Autowired` with or without a `Provider` is definitely the best
solution.